# Wrapping text in a flex box

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a problem. At the lowest resolution, the text does not wrap. Adds wrap by inserting code into the style. The problem occurs when the text wraps, there is no equal space at the top and bottom.

```
    <header class="scHeader">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center" style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: initial;">
                <div class="col-lg-12 align-self-end">
                    <h1 class="text-white text-uppercase font-weight-bold display-4">Where does it come from?</h1>
                    <hr class="my-4 bg-primary w-25">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-12 align-self-baseline my-0">
                    <p class="text-white">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Zoom 100% - default
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeX8R.png

Zoom 300% - RWD (problem)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQtc0.png

````
header.scHeader { 
    padding-top: 10rem;
    padding-bottom: calc(10rem - 72px);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(10, 10, 10,.8) 0,rgba(20, 20, 20,.8) 100%),url(../img/header.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;

    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 50rem;
}

header.scHeader.row {
    height: 100%!important;
}```
````

Comment: Don't use zoom. Use Dev Console `CTRL + SHIFT + I` and switch to mobile view.

Comment: I checked it too